# Moving elements in current theme/layout

Tags: magento2, layout, theme, magento2.2.2

I decided to start learning Magento using the current 2.2.2 version. After studying a bit about it, I managed to install it and apply a themeforest theme.

Despite reading questions here and reading the documentation, I still can't figure out how to move some important blocks around.

Let's take the search bar and user links for example: How do I move these by editing the layout files? Which files am I looking to alter? Should I be doing it in the admin panel?

[image: Before]
[image: After the intended changes]

Comment: ultimo theme having a setting in back end , use that to change the position

Comment: Could you point me in the right direction? I read they're documentation and the part where the theme could be edited is missing. 
Also, I was wondering how to do it in a more general way so that I can do it regardless of the theme.

Comment: Maybe you have not installed the theme properly , Ultimo is paid theme, their support will guide you better

Comment: Yes, the theme is installed properly. They are not aswering my questions and as I said, I am looking for a more general approach to editing layouts in magento

Answer (score 0):

You have to use  element for rearranging the elements in layouts. For more info,

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html#layout_markup_rearrange

Comment: @cractastic follow this doc